# Why does my JS file not get loaded?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner with Drupal. I want to include a JavaScript file using a custom module.

I created the .libraries.yml file, *hello_world.libraries.yml*.

```yaml
hello_world_js:
  js:
    js/basic.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

The module .info.yml file (*hello_worl.info.yml*) contains a reference to the library.

```yaml
name: Hello World
type: module
description: Say Hello World
package: Custom
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - hello_world/hello_world_js
```

The JavaScript code in the *basic.js* file is the following one.

```javascript
(function($,Drupal){
  Drupal.behaviors.addAccessionBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings){
      $(".query_button").click(function(){
        console.log("works");
      });
    }
  };
})(JQuery, Drupal);
```

When I click on a button using the *.query_button* CSS class, nothing happens and I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in a JavaScript console you can get more information. You probably have an error in your console that says `JQuery is not defined`. This is  because you declared `JQuery` but the variable is `jQuery`. So this:

```
})(JQuery, Drupal);
```

Should be this:

```
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Also, when you want to test if your file has been attached, you should add a debugging command directly into behaviors.attach(), rather than a sub-function that requires a click (as you've done). So you can test if your script has been added like this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.addAccessionBehavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings){
    console.log("works");
    $(".query_button").click(function(){
      // Do stuff on click
    });
  }
};
```

This will log something on page load, which tells you that the script has loaded (and contains required variables).

Answer (score 0):

Module info files have no `libraries` key. That key is only for themes.

You need to attach the module library yourself. Read the docs; there are [numerous ways to attach the library](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#s-attaching-a-library-to-pages) at the right place to be loaded at the right time, depending on where you need the JS to fire.

Finally fix this typo: JQuery with uppercase J is wrong. It needs to be `jQuery` with lowercase j.